# How to obfuscate Windows phone 7 code

Tags: silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7

How to obfuscate Windows phone 7 code?Have any tools for it?

Comment: DotFuscator. You should have installed it along with your SDK.

Comment: If you are thinking of obfuscating your code at this stage, it's not worth stealing your code at this stage is it? If your app if code complete then go ahead and obfuscate it if you think it's that valuable.

Comment: Dotfuscator is free for Windows Phone for now, however, there was an announcement that there would be a change in December (I don't remember the date).  What that change is, we don't know, but they were putting it out there because they had stated in the past that they would not cancel the program without 60 days notice.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you separating this from C#/ Silverlight ? aren't windows phone application written in C#/ Silverlight? , it doesn't matter whether you're writing this for windows phone or for a C# console/Windows forms Application.

There're some tools you can use them for general C#:

[Aldaray](http://www.aldaray.com/Rummage?gclid=CP25w7mxkqwCFUMm3god8UddnQ)

[XHEO](http://xheo.com/products/code-protection/tour/obfuscation?gclid=CNr7kpSykqwCFQSFDgod5z-9qA)

[Semantic Designs C# obfuscator](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Obfuscators/CSharpObfuscator.html)

And these are some .NET assemblies FREE obfuscators:

[Freeware .NET Obfuscator Skater Light Edition 1.0](http://www.freedownloadscenter.com/Programming/IDEs_and_Coding_Utilities/Freeware__NET_Obfuscator_Skater_Light_Edition.html)

[.NET Confuser](http://confuser.codeplex.com/)

[Babel .NET](http://www.babelfor.net/)